# VS2015 Can't build any projects

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am not sure how this came to be exactly, but as of today I can't build anything at all in Visual Studio 2015 (community edition).

Even when creating a brand new project, console, winforms, class lib makes no difference, all I get when I try to build is the infamous "The operation could not be completed" popup. I have tried disabling the visual studio hosting process in the project properties, but to no avail.

It's really frustrating since I can't actually work on any projects at all right now. It feels like this should be a well-known issue, but searching here and on google only gives vaguely similar results but I can't find anything matching fully.

Please advise if I can access an error log or something like that to give more info.

Comment: Can you compile from the command line using MSBuild?

Comment: I get this problem, too frequently, as well. I find that shutting down Visual Studio and restarting it, resolves the issue for a while. I have performed a setup repair of Visual Studio multiple times. I just logged a bug report on Visual Studio Connect, in case you'd like to vote for it: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1873409/the-operation-could-not-be-completed-the-parameter-is-incorrect

Comment: Restarting VS didn't solve it for me, but I have since reinstalled the program entirely and that fixed it. Doesn't seem like much of a solution to post as an answer though since I don't know what the cause was. I'll take a look at your report though.